# How to send form data to php server with flask?

Tags: php, python, forms, flask

Is there any way to send form data to php server with flask?
The PHP script should behave as if it were receiving request fro a popular browser.

[OR]

Is there a pythonic way to do this: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, there are lots even, if you want to use the standard library, look at [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2), a really good module would be the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. Here is an example using `requests`: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#more-complicated-post-requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your HTML using whatever you want with Flask, and then in the action option of the form tag, you specifiy the URL where the PHP can handle that